# How to persist an entity related to an already existing one?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I have seen a lot of examples about cascading with doctrine (including the doc) but every single example is about creating eg a new user, a new comment and saving both.

In my case **the post and the user already exist**, not the comment.

The classes look like this:
[image]

My question is the following: with this kind of complexe scheme, which entity should be persisted / merged and in which order when saving a comment on an existing post by an existing user ?

I don't want code, just an explanation about how it works, that's why I don't include the code. Thanks.

Comment: `(new Comment())->setUser($user)->setPost($post)` then persist this new `Comment`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will just need to set the `Author` and `Post` and then `persist` the new comment:

```
$comment->setAuthor($yourAuthor)
        ->setPost($yourPost);
$em->persist($comment);
$em->flush();
```

Here I did not pay too much attention to Answers[], because you did not explain the relationship. However, if `Answer` is another `Comment` and if a `Comment` can be an `Answer` to only another `Comment`, then you might need adding  a `Replied` field, which will be a `Comment` and essentially a foreign key, so all the comments inside Answers[] will have a Replied field, which is the `Comment` whose Answered[] contains the other `Comment`.

Comment: Worked perfectly thanks. I forgot the `parent` field in the question, there's a bidirectionnal OneToMany with `parent` and `answers[]`.

Answer (score 1):

Cascading doesn't really help you in this case, since I imagine that you have a standalone (not embedded) `CommentType` form. So you get a `Comment` object in your controller which you have to persist, associated to already existing `User` and `Post` entities.

Cascading would be useful if you had a `PostType` form for example with an embedded `CommentType` form (through a `comment` field) and you wanted to persist (or update) both a `Post` and a `Comment` entity.

I would suggest to add a `post_id` field in your `CommentType` Form and use a DataTransformer like Symfony documentation suggests [here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/data_transformers.html#creating-the-transformer) to transform the `post_id` to a `Post` entity. Finally all you'll have to do is explicitly set your user in your controller:

```
...
$comment = new Comment();
$form = $this->createForm(CommentType::class, $comment);

$form->handleRequest($request);

if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
    $comment->setUser($this->getUser());
    $em->persist($comment);
    $em->flush();
}
```